# Get ISO week day and week of year in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a calendar heat-map by using d3.js. But i need to start the week days in Monday rather than the Sunday in default calendar heat-map. So is there any way to get the week of the year and weekday in ISO format

```
 var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "day")
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d3.time.weekOfYear(d) * cellSize;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.getDay() * cellSize;
        })
```

The code for calculating week day and week year in the  above code are

```
 d.getDay() and  d3.time.weekOfYear(d)
```

respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Intervals.md#dayOfYear),

> weekOfYear is an alias for sundayOfYear

So, it seems to me that the solution you seek is just changing what you have right now:

```
d3.time.sundayOfYear(date)
```

For this:

```
d3.time.mondayOfYear(date)
```

Comment: Got it. Made some modification for getDay to make an ISO calender. The link for iso calender in d3 https://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/cjj395zv/

Comment: `mondayOfYear` won't yield an ISO week number, though, as the first ISO 8601 week is the one that contains the first Thursday.